# IntelliJ Groovy version

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, version

I'm in the process of upgrading a project to Groovy v1.6. When I installed IntelliJ, my `GROOVY_HOME` environment variable was pointing to Groovy v1.5.7, but now that I've changed `GROOVY_HOME` to point to v1.6, it's not clear whether IntelliJ is also using the more recent version.

How can I check which version of Groovy IntelliJ is using?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use the File -> Project Structure menu item.  Then look at your Libraries and Facets (expand for Groovy) options.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Add Framework Support":

Right click on your module and choose "Add Framework Support...". There you can add/change the groovy version

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/09/groovy-related-configuration-changes/

Comment: Not showing up in my Add Framework Support menu, even though I've already installed the plugin and am successfully using an older version of Groovy....

Answer (score 1):

Found this old thread looking for a similar thing, but ended up figuring it out myself.

In my case, the project was boostrapped with [Gradle](https://gradle.org). I didn't have a standalone Groovy version installed on my machine.

Open `Tools -> Groovy Console...`, and type pretty much any command and run it. It showed me the path to Gradle cache, which included Groovy version, near the top of the new window:

```
.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/...
```

Also check `build.gradle` as it may have some hints as to which version the project uses.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays(2023) it's: File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries, locate the current groovy version, then click "Change Version".